# Passed arrays in helm values don't have array separators when charts are built

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I Have a configmap template which looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.configmap.name }}
data:
  config.yaml: |-
{{ tpl .Values.configmap.template . | indent 4 }}
```

And this is how I use it in my chart:

```yaml
# values.config.yaml
configmap:
  name: "some-name"
  template: |-
    list: {{ .Values.config.list }}
---
# values.yaml
config:
  list: [7, 8]
```

When I build charts using this command: `helm template -f values.yaml -f values.config.yaml app .` the generated values are not properly generated.
Look at this built chart:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "some-name"
data:
  config.yaml: |-
    list: [7 8]
```

As you can see the list doesn't have any **separators**.
Do you know why the separators get lost in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem occurs because helm is converting them to string as they are used in a string.
This is how I managed to solve the problem:

```yaml
list: [{{- join ", " .Values.config.list }}]
```

if the list is empty it will be: `list: []`.
If not it will be a list separated by `,`.
For example: `list: [1, 2, 3]`